# Parsing XML with Python xml.sax: How does one "keep track" of where in the tree you are?

Tags: python, xml, sax

I need to regularly export XML files from our Administration software.

This is the first time I'm using XML Parsing in Python. The XML with `xml.sax` isn't terribly difficult, but what is the best way to "keep track" of where in the XML tree you are?

For example, I have a list of our customers. I want to extract the Telephone by , but there are multiple places where  occurs:

```
eExact -> Accounts -> Account -> Contacts -> Contact -> Addresses -> Address  -> Phone
eExact -> Accounts -> Account -> Contacts -> Contact -> Phone
eExact -> Accounts -> Account -> Phone
```

So I need to keep to keep track of where exactly in the XML tree I am in order to get the *right* Phone number

As far as I can figure out from the xml.sax documentation at the Python website, there is no "easy" method or variable that is set.

So, this is what I did:

```
import xml.sax

class Exact(xml.sax.handler.ContentHandler):
  def __init__(self):
    self.curpath = []

  def startElement(self, name, attrs):
    self.curpath.append(name)

    if name == 'Phone':
      print self.curpath, name

  def endElement(self, name):
    self.curpath.pop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  parser = xml.sax.make_parser()
  handler = Exact()
  parser.setContentHandler(handler)
  parser.parse(open('/home/cronuser/xml/mount/daily/debtors.xml'))
```

This is not very difficult, but since I don't have a lot of experience with XML I wonder if this the "generally accepted" or "best possible" manner?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks or all the comments.

I looked at  ElementTree's iterparse, but by then I already did quite some code in xml.sax. Since the immediate advantage of iterparse is small to nonexistent I choose to just stick with xml.sax. It's already a large advantage over the current solution.

Alright, so this is what I did in the end.

```
class Exact(xml.sax.handler.ContentHandler):
    def __init__(self, stdpath):
        self.stdpath = stdpath

        self.thisrow = {}
        self.curpath = []
        self.getvalue = None

        self.conn = MySQLConnect()
        self.table = None
        self.numrows = 0

    def __del__(self):
        self.conn.close()

        print '%s rows affected' % self.numrows

    def startElement(self, name, att):
        self.curpath.append(name)

    def characters(self, data):
        if self.getValue is not None:
            self.thisrow[self.getValue.strip()] = data.strip()
            self.getValue = None

    def endElement(self, name):
        self.curpath.pop()

        if name == self.stdpath[len(self.stdpath) - 1]:
            self.EndRow()
            self.thisrow = { }

    def EndRow(self):
        self.numrows += MySQLInsert(self.conn, self.thisrow, True, self.table)
        #for k, v in self.thisrow.iteritems():
        #   print '%s: %s,' % (k, v),
        #print ''

    def curPath(self, full=False):
        if full:
            return ' > '.join(self.curpath)
        else:
            return ' > '.join(self.curpath).replace(' > '.join(self.stdpath) + ' > ', '')
```

I then subclass this a number of times for different XML files:

```
class Debtors(sqlimport.Exact):
    def startDocument(self):
        self.table = 'debiteuren'
        self.address = None

    def startElement(self, name, att):
        sqlimport.Exact.startElement(self, name, att)

        if self.curPath(True) == ' > '.join(self.stdpath):
            self.thisrow = {}
            self.thisrow['debiteur'] = att.get('code').strip()
        elif self.curPath() == 'Name':
            self.getValue = 'naam'
        elif self.curPath() == 'Phone':
            self.getValue = 'telefoon1'
        elif self.curPath() == 'ExtPhone':
            self.getValue = 'telefoon2'
        elif self.curPath() == 'Contacts > Contact > Addresses > Address':
            if att.get('type') == 'V':
                self.address = 'Contacts > Contact > Addresses > Address '
        elif self.address is not None:
            if self.curPath() == self.address + '> AddressLine1':
                self.getValue = 'adres1'
            elif self.curPath() == self.address + '> AddressLine2':
                self.getValue = 'adres2'
        else:
            self.getValue = None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    handler = Debtors(['Debtors', 'Accounts', 'Account'])
    parser = xml.sax.make_parser()
    parser.setContentHandler(handler)

    parser.parse(open('myfile.xml', 'rb'))
```

... and so forth ...

Answer (score 4):

I used sax too, but then I found a better tool: [iterparse from ElementTree](http://effbot.org/zone/element-iterparse.htm).

It is similar to sax, but you can retrieve elements with contents, to free the memory you just have to clear element once retrieved.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a specific reason you need to use SAX for this?

Because, if loading the entire XML file into an in-memory object model is acceptable, you'd probably find it a lot easier to use the ElementTree DOM API.

(If you don't need the ability to retrieve a parent node when given a child, cElementTree in the Python standard library should do the trick nicely. If you do, the LXML library provides an ElementTree implementation that'll give you parent references. Both use compiled C modules for speed.)

Comment: The XML files are over 100MB and growing with about ~100MB every year, so this isn't an option.

Comment: In that case, my next suggestion would've been ElementTree's iterparse but dw0rm beat me to it... though I pity you for having to do what you're doing. That definitely sounds like a job that should've been done using something other than XML. (Probably a database)

Comment: Yes, don't get me started on *that* ... Unfortunately it's the only solution available ...

Comment: No worries. I'm know all too well what it feels like to have to use "What were they thinking!? *Were* they thinking?" technology.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest solution is exactly what you are doing in your example - maintain a stack of nodes.